# How can I change a huge text file from ANSI to UTF-8?

Tags: editor, ansi

I have a text file whose size is 1.3 GB. Most of text editors (including NotePad++) cannot open it. I need to change its format from ANSI to UTF-8. In what program can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Try EmEditor. It supports Huge files very well. Free version exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a free (and open source) command-line tool that can run on Windows, and which allows you to convert huge files from ANSI to UTF-8 (or any other encodings), you can use this tool that I've just created (runs on nodejs and uses the iconv-lite library):

https://github.com/sorin-postelnicu/convert-file-encoding

You can use it like this:

```
node bin\convertFileEncoding.js -f latin-1 -t utf-8 -i myinputfile.txt -o myoutputfile.txt
```

It is fast and supports converting very large files with minimal memory consumption (around 20MB of RAM no matter the size of the input file).

Comment: This process is nice in that it can handle really any sized file, and you can use the same input  / output encodings in order to fix up corrupted encodings

Answer (score 0):

You can also use shareware text editor [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultraedit.html).

First, configure UltraEdit for editing large files according to power tip [large file text editor](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/large_file_handling.html).

Then open your file in UltraEdit and use **File - Save As** and select for **Encoding** (Windows 7/8/8.1/Vista) respectively **Format** (Windows XP/2000) the option *UTF-8 - NO BOM*  or *UTF-8* for saving with conversion to UTF-8 encoding without or with [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at beginning of the file.